# Add hyperlinks to cells (and/or rows) of DT table in flexdashboard

Tags: r, dt, flexdashboard

I have a large table which I would like to present in interactive (filterable and sortable) form within a flexdashboard. I have achieved this using the DT package. One of the columns contains URLs, which currently are not 'clickable', so users will have to copy and paste into their browser. Is there a way to make these URLs into hyperlinks?

I have tried adding html tags in this format:

`<a href=\"https://www.website-address.co.uk/something/or/other">Link text</a>`

But the tags themselves display in the table, with no hyperlink.

Another related question - as these URLs are taking up a large proportion of the width of the table, is it possible to make an entire row 'clickable', directing users to the URL stored in 'column B' of the table, without displaying 'column B'?

The other answers I have found apply to using DT in JavaScript or shiny, and seem not to match my code.

Thank you :)

Example code:

```
df <- data.frame(fruit = c("apple", "pear", "banana"), 
             colour = c("red", "green", "yellow"), 
             website = c("<a href=\"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple#/media/File:Red_Apple.jpg\">Apple</a>", "<a href=\"https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pear\">Pear</a>", "<a href=\"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana#/media/File:Bananas.jpg\">Banana</a>"))

datatable(df)
```

Comment: Welcome! It would be super helpful if you edited your question to provide a small, reproducible example of what you would want. You would be much more likely to get help that way. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! And sorry not to reply to this sooner. @Ugur Dar has already answered my question, but I've added in some example code for completeness :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `escape=FAlSE` argument in `datatable()` function.

Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(textLink=paste0('<a href=\"https://www.website-address.co.uk/something/or/other">Link text</a>'))

datatable(df, escape = FALSE)
```